# SQL Server NULL DATE issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, crystal-reports

How can i remove this in my crystal report . this value is showing  if my date field in null . "1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM". I don't want to show thin is my report.

I have two dates , case open date and case close date . if the case is not closed its showing this value so i want to remove this.

I am using sqlsever.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a crystal reports issue. Are you sure the date is coming out as null from the sql server?

You can use

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CloseCaseDate = '01/01/1900 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE CloseCaseDate END AS CloseCaseDate
```

if it is coming out as the 1st Jan 1900 date from sql.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal report automatically put empty string when there is `null`. However you may create an expression via Format editor. Open the crystal report designer page, select that (date) field, right click on it and select open `Format Object`.

Comment: I'm about to respond but you go ahead me! 
formatting the object would resolve the problematic date filed in crystal report.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Justin's answer, you can use SQLServer's NULLIF function:

```
select ...
       NULLIF(CloseCaseDate, '01/01/1900 00:00:00') as CloseCaseDate,
       ...
```

Comment: Yep, cleaner than mine. Often forget about NULLIF.